# Is there any disadantage in reduce belly fat by machines or by medical treatments

Tags: body-fat

I saw lot of companies advertising in online or in TV that we can reduce belly fat by using their machines. Is that really works , Is there any disadvantages  ?

also i saw some take medical treatments for removing extra fat present only in belly part ? what affects will happen on health ?

[image]

Comment: You cannot eliminate fat from certain body locations by exercising those locations. It doesn't work like that. Losing fat is achieved by burning more calories than you consume. Period. Do that and you will lose fat.

Comment: As for surgery, there are a couple of types and they're vastly different. I think you need to make that a question all its own.